# Exercício deveria mostrar um resultado mas mostra 3

Tags: java

Um algoritmo que leia 3 valores inteiros, não repetidos, e mostre em ordem decrescente. Porém ele está mostrando 3 resultados, e deve ser só 1

```
package praticando;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Exercicio2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


      Scanner valor = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite o primeiro número: ");
        int A = valor.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Digite o segundo número: ");
        int B = valor.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Digite o terceiro número: ");
        int C = valor.nextInt();

        if (A == B || B == C || A== C) {
        System.out.println("Existem números repetidos!");
    } 
         if (A > B & A > C) { //A é o maior
            } if(B > C){
              System.out.println(+A+" -> "+B+" -> "+C);
            } else {
              System.out.println(+A+" -> "+C+" -> "+B);
        }

          if (B > A & B > C) { //B é o maior
            }  if(A > C){
              System.out.println(+B+" -> "+A+" -> "+C);
            } else {
              System.out.println(+B+" -> "+C+" -> "+A);
        }

        if (C > A & C > B) { //C é o maior
        } if(A > B){
              System.out.println(+C+" -> "+A+" -> "+B);
         }else{
              System.out.println(+C+" -> "+B+" -> "+A);
        }


    } 

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Tem algumas coisas esquisitas no código. Acho que queria usar `&&` e não `&`. E não entendi porque faz um `if` que abre e fecha sem executar nada ali. Resolvido isto funciona perfeitamente. Se tivesse indentado corretamente perceberia que tem algo errado. Eu sempre falo que capricho ao escrever o código é importante, mas em geral muita gente ignora, acha que tem algum ganho escrever de qualquer jeito, quando é o oposto. Veja como caprichado fica mais fácil ver o erro, pegue o seu código e organize melhor.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Exercicio2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner valor = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite o primeiro número: ");
        int A = valor.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o segundo número: ");
        int B = valor.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o terceiro número: ");
        int C = valor.nextInt();
        if (A == B || B == C || A == C) {
            System.out.println("Existem números repetidos!");
        } 
        if (A > B && A > C) { //A é o maior
            if (B > C) System.out.println(A + " -> " + B + " -> " + C);
            else System.out.println(A + " -> " + C + " -> " + B);
        }
        if (B > A && B > C) { //B é o maior
            if (A > C) System.out.println(B + " -> " + A + " -> " + C);
            else System.out.println(B + " -> " + C + " -> " + A);
        }
        if (C > A && C > B) { //C é o maior
            if (A > B) System.out.println(C + " -> " + A + " -> " + B);
            else System.out.println(C + " -> " + B + " -> " + A);
        }
    } 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/X2aAdF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Sort3Items). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Sorte3Items.java).

Tem como otimizar isto, mas não vou mexer nesta parte, é bem simples, fica de exercício.

Comment: Olá, quanto a indentação, peço desculpas, estou aprendendo. Na questão do if, achei que era necessário fechar um if{} para abrir outro, obrigado por esclarecer isso. A questão principal é que

Comment: ...sim, ele está rodando. O problema é que está me mostrando 3 resultados. 2 incorretos

Comment: Você deve abrir e fechar onde faz sentido para o que deseja. Eu respondi o que perguntou, se tem outros erros deveria estar na pergunta ou fazer nova pergunta, mostrando o erro, detalhando o problema.

Comment: Pois foi exatamente o que eu perguntei da primeira vez, caro amigo. Porque está retornando 3, ao invés de uma resposta. A correta.

Comment: Está retornando uma e eu demonstrei isso.

Comment: Obrigado por sua ajuda.